# Convert Oracle trigger to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers, sql-server-2000

I'm not familiar with MSSQL triggers I need to convert a Oracle trigger in to MSSQL

here's the Oracle trigger:-

```
create or replace trigger TRG_GRP_SEQ
before insert on T_USER_GROUP
for each row
begin
select count(*)  into :new.GROUPSEQUENCE from  T_USER_GROUP;
end;
```

I'm in trouble covering the before statements and for each need some helping hand.

Description: This trigger does is before inserting each row in to the table T_USER_GROUP the GROUPSEQUENCE will increment by one value determining the total count (just like ID generation)

Thanks.

Comment: For us non-Oracle gurus, could you explain what the trigger above does, please?

Comment: thanks, now it makes sense to me.  :)  :new.GROUPSEQUENCE is presumably a reference to the GROUPSEQUENCE column of the new row.

Comment: @Will A yes you got the point.

Comment: MMRUser, that Oracle trigger could have issues in a busy environment. If you want a unique GROUPSEQUENCE value it should use a sequence generator instead. Otherwise multiple rows could get the same GROUPSEQUENCE value. Maybe the app does not care if the value is not unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server can make columns `identity` which means they autoincrement for newly inserted rows. I recommend you use one, which would let you dispense with the trigger entirely.

If you already have data in your table, then you'll ned to create a new table and populate it like so:

```
CREATE TABLE T_USER_GROUP_New (
   GroupSequence int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
   <Other Columns ...>
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT T_USER_GROUP_New ON;
INSERT T_USER_GROUP_New (GroupSequence, <OtherColumns ...>)
SELECT * FROM T_USER_GROUP;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT T_USER_GROUP_New OFF;

-- Add script here to drop FK constraints from any tables with an FK to T_USER_GROUP

EXEC sp_rename 'T_USER_GROUP', 'T_USER_GROUP_Old';
EXEC sp_rename 'T_USER_GROUP_New', 'T_USER_GROUP';

-- Add script here to recreate FK constraints from any tables with an FK to T_USER_GROUP

-- Add script here to add appropriate indexes and constraints to T_USER_GROUP
-- and rename or drop them from T_USER_GROUP_Old
```

Now you can completely skip the GroupSequence column when inserting, and it will always get the next, incremented value. You can learn this value immediately after like so:

```
DECLARE @NewGroupSequenceStart int,
   @NewGroupSequenceEnd int;

INSERT T_USER_GROUP (<Columns not including GroupSequence ...>)
VALUES (<Values ...>);
-- or SELECT <Columns ...> FROM Somewhere

SELECT @NewGroupSequenceStart = Scope_Identity(), @NewGroupSequenceEnd = @@RowCount;
SET @NewGroupSequenceEnd = @NewGroupSequenceEnd + @NewGroupSequenceStart - 1;

-- Now these two variables have the start and end GroupSequence IDs
-- that were newly generated (you can insert multiple rows).
-- This could probably be cleaned up a little but I don't have time to test now.
```

Answer (score 1):

The below ought to come close to what you're after.  SQL Server does not have BEFORE triggers, so you have to use an INSTEAD OF trigger and perform the insert within that.  Also, SQL Server doesn't have row-by-row triggers, all trigger operations are set-based (inserted / deleted tables).

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_GRP_SEQ
ON T_USER_GROUP
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO T_USER_GROUP (
  ..column list...
)
SELECT ...columns...,
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY something) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_USER_GROUP),
       ...columns...
FROM inserted
```

Comment: The ROW_NUMBER() function is not supported in MSSQL 2000

Comment: You need some locking on that or you're going to have things explode some day.

Comment: @Erik - totally agree with that, such a solution should be tested to the nth degree!

Comment: @MMRUser - Ouch!  How do you survive without ROW_NUMBER and friends?  You'll need to find another means of getting a 1-based 'index' of the inserted rows.  A #temp table with an IDENTITY column and a primary key from inserted is one such means.

Comment: Actually, let me add further that even with locking, I think this is not the best solution. Locking is BAD. Since there's another solution to get the same result without locking like that, then it absolutely should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

i would like to go with Erik,

If you define

```
CREATE T_USER_GROUP (GROUPSEQUENCE INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, GROUP_NAME nvarchar(100), ...)
```

you don't need this sort of trigger. IDENTITY(1,1) means that the counter begins at 1 and increments by 1. On an

```
INSERT T_USER_GROUP(GROUP_NAME)
VALUES('NewGroupName')
```

you will get automatically the next higher value in GROUPSEQUENCE.